# Parent-Child class relation in C++ with pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

How should I go about implementing a parent-child relation in c++? I want a parent to have a single active child at a time, but I also want the child to "know" who its parent is.

1. The child class is abstract and therefore only a pointer to it can be declared in `Parent`.
2. `Child` has a protected pointer to its `Parent`, but I don't want it to own the pointer, I don't want an implementor to `delete` the memory to which the `Parent` pointer points.
3. What about pointer reassignment? A `Parent`'s active `Child` can change. That's when I `delete` the memory behind the `current_child` pointer and set it to the new `Child` pointer.

I want the `Parent` to own the current `Child` pointer and to release it when changing, but I don't want the `Child` to own its `Parent` pointer.

Should I maybe use smart pointers for this? I come from a C# background and there it's very easy to do this. Is there some pattern I haven't heard about?

This is the code I have so far:

```
#pragma once

class Child;

class Parent
{
private:
    Child* current_child = nullptr;
public:
    void ChangeChild(Child* child_ptr);
};

// Parent.cpp
void Parent::ChangeChild(Child* child_ptr)
{
    if (child_ptr == nullptr)
    {
        // throw
    }
    
    delete current_child;

    current_child = child_ptr;
}
```

And a `Child` abstract class:

```
#pragma once

#include "Parent.h"

class Child
{
protected:
    Parent* parent;
public:
    Child(Parent* parent_ptr)
    {
        parent = parent_ptr;
    }

    virtual void Do() = 0;
};
```

Comment: Don't you get a circular reference of header files problem in 1st place here?

Comment: You're right! This can probably be fixed with a forward declaration though.

Comment: I really don't understand.  By declaration, the child class knows its parents.  When a child instance is created, the parent "stuff" is also included.

Comment: Consider using smart pointers (e.g. unique_ptr or weak_ptr) as well.

Comment: Regarding your question: Using smart pointers would definitely be the better choice in your design, but you'll need to take care about ownership semantics, and also weak referencing (e.g. for the parent pointer).

Comment: More than one class can be derived from a single parent.  A pointer to a parent or base class does not guarantee that child member and functions can be accessed via the pointer to the parent class.

Comment: The `Parent` only needs to know about the functionality that the `Child` abstract class exposes.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ can you elaborate more on ownership semantics and weak referencing?

Comment: Use shared_ptr and weak_ptr for your design, that will help you and you will avoid memory issues on the future

Comment: So `shared_ptr<Child>` and `weak_ptr<Parent>` ?

Comment: ^ Yes, like this. Otherwise circular references cause memory leaks, because the pointers will block deletion since reference counting for two shared_ptr's will never go down to zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each `Child`-derived object will be destroyed when the parent is destroyed, you just need to use a `std::unique_ptr<Child>`.  For convenience, you can provide a `set_child` function that passes through the pointer to the parent for the child to store, instead of doing it in higher-level code.  You might expand that to a variadic template so it can pass an arbitrary number of argument too - google "perfect forwarding function" if that's useful to you.

(`std::shared_ptr` and `std::weak_ptr` are potentially useful if a `Child`-derived object is allowed to outlive its parent, and there might be callbacks into the `Child` functions that want to know if the parent still exists.)

Code also available at http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7dec0fba15c02953

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Parent;

struct Child {
    virtual ~Child() { }
    Child(Parent* p_parent) : p_parent_{p_parent} { }
    virtual int f() const { return 0; }
    Parent* p_parent_;
};

struct Parent
{
    std::unique_ptr<Child> p_child_;
    
    // optional convenience function - injects "this" for you +
    // provides better encapsulation if p_child_ is made private
    template <typename ChildT>
    void set_child() {
        p_child_ = std::make_unique<ChildT>(this);
    }
    
    Child& child() { return *p_child_; }
};

struct Child__1 : Child {
    using Child::Child;
    int f() const override { return 1; }
};

int main()
{
    Parent p;
    p.p_child_ = std::make_unique<Child>(&p); // direct assign
    std::cout << p.child().f() << " should be 0\n";
    p.p_child_ = std::make_unique<Child__1>(&p);
    std::cout << p.child().f() << " should b1 1\n";
    p.set_child<Child>(); // using convenience function...
    std::cout << p.child().f() << " should be 0\n";
}
```

Comment: Children are not supposed to outlive the parent (in this case).

Comment: @JohnyP.  Too easy then - just need the code as presented.  FYI /- there has been discussion of adding a `std::nonowning_ptr<>` to the language, which would make the intended semantics even more obvious than a raw pointer, but these days raw pointers should only be used for non-owning semantics, as `unique_ptr`, `shared_ptr`, `weak_ptr` cover 99% of other cases, and if you have some custom need you should probably write your own smart pointer to cover it.

Comment: What prevents someone from just doing `delete my_raw_ptr;` and deleting the memory behind it ?

Comment: @JohnyP.: encapsulation; where that's a concern - the `p_parent_` object would normally be made `private` if used in a larger body of code where client usage wasn't trusted (often lower standards of encpasulation are more concise and convenient for some support code local to a single implementation file)

Comment: @JohnyP. a class can always access its own private members, and either provide `Parent& parent() { return *p_parent_; }` and `const Parent& parent() const { return *p_parent_; }` functions or make `p_parent_` protected so derived classes implementing the `Child` interface can access `p_parent_`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get all the constraints in your design, but the following is a start:

```cpp
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class Node {
 public:
  /// @brief A Node with no parent and no children.
  explicit Node() noexcept : m_child{nullptr}, m_parent{nullptr} {
    std::cout << "Node(" << this << ")\n";
  }

  /// @brief Destructor.
  /// @note Written just to echo destruction. In practice, default-provided is
  /// sufficient.
  ~Node() noexcept { std::cout << "~Node(" << this << ")\n"; }

  /// @brief Set the child of this Node.
  /// @param[in] node Node to set as child.
  /// @note The previous child, if any, will be deleted.
  void set_child(std::unique_ptr<Node> node) {
    m_child           = std::move(node);
    m_child->m_parent = this;
  }

  /// @brief This Node's child.
  const Node* child() const { return m_child.get(); }

  /// @brief This Node's parent.
  const Node* parent() const { return m_parent; }

  /// @brief This Node's child (mutable).
  Node* child() { return m_child.get(); }

  /// @brief This Node's parent (mutable).
  Node* parent() { return m_parent; }

 private:
  std::unique_ptr<Node> m_child  = nullptr;  //!< Unique child.
  Node*                 m_parent = nullptr;  //!< Non-owning parent.
};

int main() {
  auto root = std::make_unique<Node>();
  root->set_child(std::make_unique<Node>());

  assert(root->child()->parent() == root.get());

  // previously-held child will be destroyed.
  root->set_child(std::make_unique<Node>());

  // add grandchildren
  root->child()->set_child(std::make_unique<Node>());

  // invariants
  assert(root->child()->child()->parent() == root->child());
}
```

Possible output:

```
$ clang++ example.cpp -std=c++2a -Wall -Wextra -Werror -fsanitize=address
$ ./a.out
Node(0x6020000000d0)
Node(0x6020000000f0)
Node(0x602000000110)
~Node(0x6020000000f0)
Node(0x602000000130)
~Node(0x6020000000d0)
~Node(0x602000000110)
~Node(0x602000000130)
```

Possibly the best talk I've seen on the topic is the one given by Herb Sutter ["Leak Freedom in C++... *By Default*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JfmTagWcqoE). Watch it. He goes into detail about when to use the different pointers (`shared_ptr`, `unique_ptr`, `weak_ptr`, "raw" pointer, and reference). He also discusses the issues with recursive destruction associated with deeply recursive designs.

Comment: Unique pointers for the childs will rarely meet the requirements since it's likely you want to have them shared with client applications, and keep track of these references.

Comment: My practice is to rely on unique ownership until need to share is demonstrated.

Comment: Sure, and that's a good practice. I am just talking from experience with such constructs, that you'll end up with `std::shared_ptr` as the correct design. Also did I get it wrong that a `Parent` should be able to have multiple `Child`s?

Comment: In my experience, it happens as often as not.

Comment: I am not sure whether the parent should be able to have multiple children but just one "active" (whatever that means). The question is not very clear (to me). Or maybe I'm just in a rush!

Comment: The parent has a single child always. All previous children can be deleted.

Comment: @JohnyP. Hmmm, weird design. May I ask that you elaborate about your use case in your quesiton.

Comment: The design I propose complies with that constraint. Now, you must carefully consider what @πάνταῥεῖ brought up regarding who gets to use nodes while they exist. You may be able to get away with this design, or you may need one based on `shared_ptr` that hands `weak_ptr` to clients.

Comment: @Escualo That's one reason I am avoiding to answer unclear questions.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The parent can only work with a single child at a time. Even if there are other children the parent works with the one that was given to it. I realize it could be unclear but I need that kind of design for something I'm working on.

Comment: @JohnyP. _"but I need that kind of design for something I'm working on."_ Could be you're struggling with a XY problem though. It doesn't sound from your desctiption that the `Parent` should really _own_ that child. Just as mentioned what you describe sounds to be an unusual solution.

Comment: Even if the parent doesn't own the child I still need to reassign the pointer to the new child and that would leak if it isn't deleted from outside...